# Avoid Using temporary in group by Avg

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table with three columns - appname, uid, rating.
I need to get the average rating for each appname quickly. This is my code:

```
SELECT
   t1.appname as applicationName,
   Avg(t1.rating) as averageRating
FROM
   `user_ratings` t1  
GRO
   t1.appname
```

The problem is, on my embedded server this takes a few seconds, and can even fail if the /tmp fills up (I can't do anything about this, I also can't edit my.cfg). Therefore I want to do this without using temporary.

Here is output of EXPLAIN, showing that tmp is used as expected:

`1  SIMPLE  t1  ALL                 6399    Using temporary; Using filesort`

Without the Avg, the query completes instantly, and produces this EXPLAIN:

`1  SIMPLE  t1  index       appname 452     6399    Using index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INDEX(appname, rating)
```

This is optimal for the `GROUP BY`, and it is "covering" -- that is, all the data needed for the query is in the index, no need to reach into the 'data' (which is a separate BTree).

Partitioning would *not* help.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. I have to read up on covering indexes.

Comment: My quick discussion on them:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1  Plus a longer "cookbook":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: @RickJames I read through mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1  its really interesting, is whats written in their still apply today?

Comment: @Kay - Thanks for asking.  I reviewed it just now; it continues to look relevant and correct even for the latest MySQL and MariaDB.  I should probably emphasize getting rid of `INDEX(a)` when you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.  (I'll update it soon.)  I point that out in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql , where it is more important.  If you would like a deeper discussion of something, feel free to start a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

The "heavy" part of your query is the **GROUP BY**.

Try to set *appname* as primary index, or partitioning by this field.

Comment: Appname has duplicates and can't be a primary, and I don't have the partitioning plugin (old version of MySQL).